# Client Server Connection's Message

Tags: c#

```
server = new Server(textBox3.Text, "90");
server.EncryptionEnabled = false;
server.OnClientConnected += new OnConnectedDelegate(server_OnClientConnected);
server.OnClientDisconnected += new OnDisconnectedDelegate(server_OnClientDisconnected);
server.OnDataReceived += new OnReceivedDelegate(server_OnDataReceived);
server.OnServerError += new OnErrorDelegate(server_OnServerError);

server.Start();

MessageBox.Show("Connected");
```

The Message Box still appears if the connection is error. The error message will display in

```
void server_OnServerError(object Sender, ErrorArguments R)
{
    MessageBox.Show(R.ErrorMessage);
}
```

I try to use several ways to such as if-else statement to show if the server is connected successfully but still fail to do so. For my question, how to know that the server is connected? Sorry for my bad Question.

Comment: What is this Server class you are using in your example?
What do you mean by "server is connected"? .. connected to who?

Comment: Sorry for it, I mean how I know the Server is started?

Comment: Then I guess Darek W gave you the answer :)

Comment: whats a server, your not talking about the server class (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.aspx) as non of these methods are on this class. None of this makes sense?

Comment: @user2650977: What about the approach that I suggested? If your server object cannot start, it will throw a exception - correct? If not, you can always try a test call to the server - which ought to throw an exception if the server is not connected.

Answer (score 0):

A try/catch might work nicely.

```
try 
{
    server.Start();
    // server.SomeTestCall(); - Try this if Start() does not throw an exception
    // when failing to actually start the server
    MessageBox.Show("Server is started.");
}
catch
{
    server.Dispose();
    MessageBox.Show("Server failed to start.");
}
```